# How to run java threads sequentially on Android

Tags: java, android

I have seven sonar sensors and I aim to display these sensor values sequentially on an Android tablet.

To dynamically display the sensor values on the tablet screen, I used `Runnable`s.

However, if the sonar sensors work in parallel, it causes interference between sonar sensors. Therefore, I need to make them work sequentially.

My question is : is it possible to use threads sequentially to display sensor values on an Android Tablet?

Although I used `join()` and `sleep()`, still the sensors are interfering with each other. When I tried to use wait and notify, the application gives an out of memory exception. I also tried to use synchronized methods but it didn't affect it.

Below you can see my code.

```
package com.dinning;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class Dinning implements Runnable 
{
    public Interfacekit diningkit;
    public TextView[] Rfidviews; 
    int count=1;

    public Dinning(Interfacekit diningkit,Rfid drfid1,Rfid drfid2, Rfid drfid3,Rfid drfid4,Rfid drfid5,Rfid drfid6,Rfid fsrfid1,Rfid fsrfid2,Rfid fsrfid3,final TextView[] Rfidviews)
    {
        this.diningkit = diningkit;
        this.Rfidviews = Rfidviews;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run()       
    {
        while(count==1)
        {   
            if(diningkit.getattach()==true)
            {
                Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() 
                {  
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        Rfidviews[11].post(new Runnable() 
                        {
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                {
                                    int sonar0 = diningkit.getsonar(7);
                                    if(sonar0!=0)
                                        Rfidviews[11].setText("Port0:"+sonar0);
                                    else
                                        Rfidviews[11].setText(" ");
                                }            
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {  
                    public void run() {
                        Rfidviews[12].post(new Runnable() 
                        {
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                {
                                    int sonar1 = diningkit.getsonar(6);
                                    if(sonar1!=0)
                                        Rfidviews[12].setText("Port1:"+sonar1);
                                    else
                                        Rfidviews[12].setText(" ");
                                }            
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() 
                {  
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        Rfidviews[13].post(new Runnable() 
                        {
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                {
                                    int sonar2 = diningkit.getsonar(5);     
                                    if(sonar2!=0)
                                        fidviews[13].setText("Port2:"+sonar2);
                                    else
                                        Rfidviews[13].setText(" ");
                                }        
                            }
                        });
                    }       
                });

                t1.start();
                t2.start();
                t3.start();
            } 
        }//while        
    }           
}





 package com.dinning;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import com.phidgets.InterfaceKitPhidget;
import com.phidgets.Phidget;
import com.phidgets.PhidgetException;
import com.phidgets.event.AttachEvent;
import com.phidgets.event.AttachListener;
import com.phidgets.event.DetachEvent;
import com.phidgets.event.DetachListener;
import com.phidgets.event.InputChangeEvent;
import com.phidgets.event.InputChangeListener;
import com.phidgets.event.SensorChangeEvent;
import com.phidgets.event.SensorChangeListener;

public class Interfacekit {

    int status=1;
    InterfaceKitPhidget ik;
    public boolean attach = false;
    public Phidget phidget;
    int value = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int serial;

    int value0,value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,valport;
    int sonarvalue0,sonarvalue1,sonarvalue2,sonarvalue3,sonarvalue4,sonarvalue5,sonarvalue6,sonarvalue7;
    int curVal;

    public Interfacekit(final Context con,final Activity act,int serial)
    {
        this.serial = serial;

        try
        {
            com.phidgets.usb.Manager.Initialize(con);
            ik = new InterfaceKitPhidget();



            ik.addAttachListener(new AttachListener() {
                public void attached(final AttachEvent ae)
                {
                    act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            try{
                            attach=true;    

                            value0= ik.getSensorValue(0);
                            value1= ik.getSensorValue(1);
                            value2= ik.getSensorValue(2);
                            value3=ik.getSensorValue(3);
                            value4=ik.getSensorValue(4);
                            value5= ik.getSensorValue(5);
                            value6= ik.getSensorValue(6);
                            value7= ik.getSensorValue(7);


                            }catch(Exception e){}
                        }

                    });




                }
            });



            ik.addDetachListener(new DetachListener() {
                public void detached(final DetachEvent ae) {

                    attach = false;
                    phidget = ae.getSource();
                    act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });


            ik.addSensorChangeListener(new SensorChangeListener() {
                public void sensorChanged(SensorChangeEvent se) {  //final Sensorchangeevent


                    value = se.getValue();
                    index = se.getIndex();



                    try {

                        sonarvalue0=ik.getSensorValue(0);
                        sonarvalue1=ik.getSensorValue(1);
                        sonarvalue2=ik.getSensorValue(2);
                        sonarvalue3=ik.getSensorValue(3);
                        sonarvalue4=ik.getSensorValue(4);
                        sonarvalue5=ik.getSensorValue(5);
                        sonarvalue6=ik.getSensorValue(6);
                        sonarvalue7=ik.getSensorValue(7);





                    } catch (PhidgetException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }









                }



            });




            ik.addInputChangeListener(new InputChangeListener() {
                public void inputChanged(final InputChangeEvent ie) {



                }
            });
            ik.open(serial);

        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }



        public boolean getattach()
        {

         return attach ;    
        }

        /* Sonar*/

        public int getsonar(int digitalOutput){

            int curVal,result = 0;


            if(5==digitalOutput){



                    try {
                        ik.setOutputState(digitalOutput, true);

                    } 
                    catch (PhidgetException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                    curVal=(int) (1.296*sonarvalue2);

                    if(curVal>0 && curVal<60){
                        result=curVal;
                        System.out.println("Port2: "+result);
                    }
                    else if (curVal>60)
                        result=0;



            }

            else if(6==digitalOutput){



                try {
                    ik.setOutputState(digitalOutput, true);

                } 
                catch (PhidgetException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                }



                curVal=(int) (1.296*sonarvalue1);

                if(curVal>0 && curVal<80)
                    result=curVal;

                else if(curVal>80) 
                    result=0;



            }


            else if(7==digitalOutput){



                try {
                    ik.setOutputState(digitalOutput, true);

                } 
                catch (PhidgetException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                }



                curVal=(int) (1.296*sonarvalue0);

                if(curVal>0 && curVal<50)
                    result=curVal;

                else if(curVal>50)
                    result=0;



            }

            return result;

    }





        /* End Sonar*/



}
```

Comment: Any reason to use threads at all if all you want to do is execute stuff sequentially?

Comment: simple solution to replace tX.start() with tX.run() :-) and here comes the sequential call

Comment: Looks like the class is a UI component, so he may be trying to avoid blocking calls on the Android UI thread

Comment: As far as I know, I need to use threads for all sensors in order to display sensor values on Android. However, as I mentioned in my question, if they are working in parallel, they interference between them.

Comment: I never understand these questions. If you want sequential execution why are you using threads? Perhaps what you want is *serial* execution, in which case you just need to use some synchronization.

Comment: Since without threads it is not possible to display sensor values in Textviews on Android Tablet. In other words, Textviews need thread for dynamically showing sensor values on Android Tablet. But can you open a bit more how can I use synchronization in Java for my case?

Answer (score 3):

Use ExecutorService in java.util.concurrent package. In particular Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

> **newSingleThreadExecutor**
>
> *public static ExecutorService newSingleThreadExecutor()
> Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an unbounded queue. (Note however that if this single thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.) **Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially**, and no more than one task will be active at any given time. Unlike the otherwise equivalent newFixedThreadPool(1) the returned executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional threads.*

Also

```
t1.start();
t1.join();
t2.start();
```

etc. Start one when the other dies. However I don't see the need for threads at all. Needless complication and against the design purpose of them?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {  
                public void run() {
                   //do something
                }
            });
```

which runs the `run()` method in a thread.

Try

```
(new Runnable() {  
    public void run() {
        //do something
    }
 }).run();
```

which creates the anonymous `Runnable` and calls its `run()` directly (rather than via a `Thread`), and is hence executed sequentially.

**Edit 0**:
You seem to have lots of `Thread`s and `Runnable`s for no clear reason. I believe this code should be equivalent, but simplifies away a lot of the `Thread`s and `Runnable`s that make it confusing to read:

```
package net.ukims.dsp.cid.dataaccess;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class Dinning implements Runnable {
    public Interfacekit diningkit;
    public TextView[] Rfidviews;
    int count = 1;

    public Dinning(Interfacekit diningkit, Rfid drfid1, Rfid drfid2,
            Rfid drfid3, Rfid drfid4, Rfid drfid5, Rfid drfid6, Rfid fsrfid1,
            Rfid fsrfid2, Rfid fsrfid3, final TextView[] Rfidviews) {
        this.diningkit = diningkit;
        this.Rfidviews = Rfidviews;
        run();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (count == 1) {
            if (diningkit.getattach() == true) {
                Rfidviews[11].post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        {
                            int sonar0 = diningkit.getsonar(7);
                            if (sonar0 != 0)
                                Rfidviews[11].setText("Port0:" + sonar0);
                            else
                                Rfidviews[11].setText(" ");
                        }
                    }
                });

                Rfidviews[12].post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        {
                            int sonar1 = diningkit.getsonar(6);
                            if (sonar1 != 0)
                                Rfidviews[12].setText("Port1:" + sonar1);
                            else
                                Rfidviews[12].setText(" ");
                        }
                    }
                });

                Rfidviews[13].post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        {
                            int sonar2 = diningkit.getsonar(5);
                            if (sonar2 != 0)
                                fidviews[13].setText("Port2:" + sonar2);
                            else
                                Rfidviews[13].setText(" ");
                        }
                    }
                });             
            }
        }// while
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But I still have a question. Because if you look at Dining constructor, I am using "new Thread(this).start(); " this calls diningkit (which provides sensor values) and rfidviews(which is Textview). So, if I creates Runnable and calls run() directly instead of Thread, how should I change "new Thread(this).start(); " in the dining constructor?

Comment: You don't need to change the constructor, because that triggers a call to `Dining.run()`, which (assuming you made the modification I suggested) is executed sequentially. However, if you feel you must for your piece of mind, you can replace `new Thread(this).start();` with `run();`

Comment: Yes, I made the modification which you suggested. And I didn't change the constructor but still I have problem because still sensors interference between them. Actual problem sensors are cross talking each other. So, other sensors should stop until one of these sensors are receiving own sound signal. But if they work in parallel, at that time incorrect values are displaying on tablet. At least I am sure if they work sequentially, I will avoid these interference problem. But I don't have that much experience about Thread, Runnable method and java programming language.

Comment: This sounds like something that is more specific to the Android platform than Java threads and concurrency. Perhaps you could update your question with more detail about the interference you're experiencing, for example, what is happening, and how is that different from what you want to happen? Are these sensors part of the Android tablet, or are they external devices that are connected to the tablet?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have to explain more details. First, these sensors are external devices which are ultra sonar sensors. There is a Phidget Interfacekit (that is kind of microcontroller) provides the connection between sonar sensors and android tablets. In theses interfacekit, there are 7 ports and sensors connect to these ports. This interfacekit is connected to Android tablet by usb cable. To run my application on Android tablet, there is a connection between my laptop and tablet. By this way, I can read sensor values from each 7 port. In java, there is a Phidget Interfacekit libraries.

Comment: I edit the code above. I also posted Interfacekit class that sensor values are read in this class.

Comment: And what do you mean by "interference"?

Comment: "The reason of interference is happening is because the sensors are not operating synchronously with each other or at the same speed. One sensor may be operating slightly faster than the other. For example; sensor 1 is operating at 49.0mS while sensor 2 operates at 49.2mS. When the sensors are not synchronized, one sensor may be in transmitting mode while the other sensor is in receiving mode. Because this action is happening, the sensor is receiving the pulses from the sender and not its own pulse bounce back." In my case I should use 7 sonar sensors together. Sensors connect to Interfacekit.

Comment: I don't think anything you've posted here is likely to affect that behaviour. Perhaps you should start a new question focussing on how to address the unsynchronised sensors. It seems to me that you're looking for some way of only updating the view when all sensors have sent a value, but I'd say that's beyond the scope of this question